# MS Graph and Sharepoint 2016 OnPrem

Tags: sharepoint, graph, on-premises-instances

Is it possible to use MS Graph to connect to a Sharepoint 2016 on prem installation?

//Thomas

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph is Microsofts API for their online services, so it wouldn't work on SharePoint OnPrem.

SharePoint 2016 has a REST API interface though. I haven't used it myself, but you can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom